# Do I need to cover an unused punched out hole in a junction box? If so, how?

Tags: wiring, junction-box

I removed a Romex cable that was going into a junction box top middle opening(you can see in the picture).

There is still an opening at that punch out.

Is it okay to leave it as is? If not, how do I cover it?

[image: junction box]

Comment: It looks too small to let in critters so probably won't cause any problem by leaving it in, but the answer below shows what you would use if you want to cover it.  To use the knockout plug (as in the answer) first you remove the threaded pass-through in the center.  Then just snap it in.

Comment: I only see two wire nuts - are the grounds tied together? If not, they should be (with a ground pigtail attached to the junction box).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "knockout fill plug" - costs a few cents (depending on supplier - some are over a buck, I'd keep shopping), snaps into the hole (take the clamp out first.)

[image: knockout fill plug]
[image: knockout fill plug]